# changing x label in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python so I apologize if this if this will sound like a silly question.
I am trying to change a the title of the x axis in a plot ,from what I read if you use subplots the you need to use `set_xlabel('X Axis')` command but for some reason this is not working for me.

```
plot=plt.subplots();
dftemp=dftemp.set_index('Date2');
plot=dftemp['yield_bruto_percent'].plot(kind='bar',color="lightgray",title=dftemp['paper_name'][1][::-1]+'    ינוציח-ימינפ גוריד ',figsize=(8,4),legend=True)
plot=dftemp['dirug_mnpik_psagot'].plot(secondary_y=True,legend=True);
plot=dftemp['final_score'].plot(secondary_y=True,legend=True);
plot=dftemp['dirug_manpik_hitzoni'].plot(secondary_y=True,legend=True,rot=45);
plot.set_xlabel('X Axis')
```

when I run this code the label does not change and the label appears as the name of variable which is the index in my data set.
This is the message i get

```
<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x23735e70390>
```

any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel.html function is a member of Axes class.

You can get an object of axes class from subplots as following

```
plot, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Then set the xlabel as following

```
ax.set_xlabel('X Axis')
```